# Thunderbird "just mark as deleted" behaviour

Tags: thunderbird

On my computer I use Thunderbird to read my Gmail account on Linux. I set it to "just mark messages as deleted". When I go to a different folder and come back, the messages that were marked as deleted disappear.

I like this behaviour and I tried to set up a friend's Thunderbird (on Windows) that's configured to use Gmail, to do the same. I didn't manage to get the marked messages to disappear when I change folders. The marked messages remain there until I compact the folder.

Is there a setting somewhere in the configuration to set the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found how to set the behaviour as requested. The difference was in the IMAP server.

Setting the IMAP server to imap.gmail.com makes messages marked as deleted to stay there until the folder is compacted.

Setting the IMAP server to imap.googlemail.com makes messages marked as deleted to stay only until you change folder and come back to it.

P.S. Make sure that the Gmail account option to auto-expunge deleted messages (Options-Forwarding & POP/IMAP) is selected.